# Unable to query data with mongoose using dates (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to query all Assistance documents that have the "inputDate" between their startDate and endDate. I've been looking on the internet for ages and I'm unable to make it work. It is suposed to retrieve the only document that right now is in my db. I'm using NodeJS+Mongoose.

The code in the controller is the following:

```
exports.getOccupation = (req, res, next) => {


    var inputDate = new Date("1999","10","13","16","0","0");
   
    Assistance.find({
        dateInterval:{
            startDate: {$lte:inputDate},
            endDate: {$gte:inputDate}
        }
    })
    .then(assistances => {
        console.log(assistances.length);
    })

}
```

The code of the model:

```
const assistanceSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user_id:{
            type: Schema.ObjectId 
        },
        place:{
            longitude:{
                type:String
            },
            latitude:{
                type:String
            }
        },
        dateInterval:{
            startDate: Date,
            endDate: Date
        }       
    },
    {timestamps:true}
);
```

[image: This is the document that I want to retrieve but I can't]

Comment: Maybe it has to do with how you define your Model, or how you connect to Mongo. Could you add these bits of code please? Also, what exactly is the name of your collection?

Comment: I believe you will need to use `$and` and nest your query within it

Comment: My connection to Mongo is fine because all of my other queries work fine. The problem has come when I have begun to use Dates. My collection name in this case is assistances but as I said my only document is the one shown in the picture. The controller code should retrieve that document and the log should print 1, but it prints 0 because it's not retrieving anything. Thanks!

Comment: The [date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) in MongoDB database as stored in _UTC datetime_.

Comment: @prasad_ what do you mean?

Comment: @LostJon I'm afraid that did'nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe that find() method accept **dateInterval.startDate** instead of **dateInterval:{startDate: ... }**.

Try change this way:

```
Assistance.find({
  $and: [
    { "dateInterval.startDate": { $lte: inputDate } },
    { "dateInterval.endDate": { $lte: inputDate } },
  ],
}).then((assistances) => {
  console.log(assistances.length);
});
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much!!! It's a bit strange because I have used that format in the find() method before and no problems. Maybe it was because of the $gte method or something. Anyway, thanks!